# Compilation Error: boost/atomic.hpp not found

Tags: boost

I have installed boost using the following command

```
sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev
```

When I am trying to compile a boost project it gives me the following compilation error

```
fatal error: boost/atomic.hpp: No such file or directory
```

I looked into /usr/include/boost This file is not there also. Can someone suggest a solution

Answer (score 3):

Boost Atomic is available since version 1.53. If not corrupted your installed version must be older than 1.53.

Comment: I just checked my boost version is 1.46. Do I need to download source code and compile it manually as I am getting old version using apt-get

Comment: @ekhan If newer prebuild is not available then you will need to build it yourself.